# Probability that the median of three numbers is in a certain range?

Tags: probability

I'm given numbers $a_{1}$ to $a_{n}$ with the caveat that all of those numbers are distinct and $n$ is a multiple of 4. How can I prove that if I select three of those numbers at random, there is an $\frac{11}{16}$ chance that the median of those three numbers is between $a_\frac{n}{4}$ and $a_\frac{3n}{4}$.

Just looking for a way to start this problem, if someone could give that it'd be great!

EDIT: Yes, my apologies, I forgot to add that the list of numbers $a_{1}$ to $a_{n}$ is in sorted order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need also that $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_n$, else take $a_{n/4} = 0$, $a_{3n/4} = 1$, and $a_i = 1000 + i$ otherwise. Also, you should specify whether you mean that the median is in $(a_{n/4},a_{3n/4})$ or in $\left[a_{n/4},a_{3n/4}\right]$ (exclusive or inclusive boundaries).

Comment: As for the solution, you can make some observations. If at least 2 of your chosen numbers are in $\left[a_{n/4}, a_{3n/4}\right]$, then so is the median. If only one of your numbers (call it $x$) is in that interval, then you have some cases: if $x$ is the smallest or largest of your 3 numbers, the median is not in the interval; if $x$ is the middle element, then it is the median and it is in the interval. You need to find the probabilities of each of these things happening.

Comment: Are you stating that the claim is true for all n, or only when n tends to infinity? Also, are the limits n/4 and 3n/4 inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: This question is a homework problem in my class. The students in my class are expressly forbidden from seeking help on-line. Please remove this question, and ban the student. If anyone can supply the identity of the student, I would be very interested to have it.

Comment: @DanielSpielman I'm sorry, but MSE doesn't reveal any private information regarding their users. See the [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).